# Query is not defined error jquery-ui.min.js

Tags: jquery-ui, compiler-errors

I am getting a Chrome console *jQuery is not defined* error for jquery-ui.min.js

In my site I put jquery call at bottom:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--JScript to Make iframe go behind footer nav upon scrolling in IE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
jQuery(document).ready(function($j){
    $j('iframe').each(function() {
        var url = $j(this).attr("src");
        if ($j(this).attr("src").indexOf("?") > 0) {
            $j(this).attr({
                "src" : url + "&wmode=transparent",
                "wmode" : "Opaque"
            });
        }
        else {
            $j(this).attr({
                "src" : url + "?wmode=transparent",
                "wmode" : "Opaque"
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The page is this: http://www.mexpro.com/mexico/auto/insurance.html

Answer (score 0):

jQuery-UI is only a plugin for jQuery. You need to add [this](http://jquery.com/download/) instead.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```